How to install teamviewer on Ubuntu 24.04
How can I download teamviewer on Ubuntu 24.04? I followed a tutorial but teamviewer does not open and does not present any error message

Install or download...?

This question is similar to: How to install deb packages (like Zoom or Chrome) in Ubuntu 24.04 using graphical method?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

For Ubuntu 24.04

sudo apt install libminizip1 gdebi-core wget
wget https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./teamviewer_amd64.deb


If you use dpkg then what is the point of installing gdebi

You problably also want to install libxcb-xinerama0 package as well. This package is the dependency of teamviewer.

Install Gdebi with sudo apt install gdebi.
Now you can open the .deb package (download from https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer_amd64.deb) with Gdebi to install it.

In case teamviewer does not run after installing, most likely that is a result of the recent changes in apparmor which is interfering with many apps. The workaround is to run the command sudo sysctl -w kernel.apparmor_restrict_unprivileged_userns=0 after every reboot.
